# create xsl file to transform attribute xml to element xml for import into access

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, import

I have an application on my Ipad that export data with xml. I want to import this file into MS Access 2007, but it's not possible (I guess due to the use of attributes) I guess when I can arrange a XSL file to that convert this attributes to elements, the import will work. I tried lots of XSL files from the internet, none of them worked till now. Can anyone help me?

Piece of XML file right from the ipad:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form name="AppVIEW">
<field name="Date" type="date"/>
<field name="Hospital" type="text"/>
<field name="ID" type="text"/>
<field name="VisitType" type="text"/>
<field name="Specialisation" type="text"/>
<field name="ContactName" type="text"/>
<field name="ContactTel" type="text"/>
<field name="ContactMail" type="text"/>
<field name="ShortText" type="text"/>
<field name="Actions" type="text"/>
<record name="OLVG">
<field name="Date">2015-10-14</field>
<field name="Hospital">OLVG</field>
<field name="ID">1</field>
<field name="VisitType">Handover</field>
<field name="Specialisation">SYS1</field>
<field name="ContactName">Nick</field>
<field name="ContactTel">0365425653</field>
<field name="ContactMail">Nick@new.nl</field>
<field name="ShortText">Dit is een test</field>
<field name="Actions">Geen verdere acties nodig</field>
</record>
</form>
```

So this must be imported into access, I guess with an XSL file. Thanks a million for your help!!

Comment: Without at the very least your desired XML format and some indication that you have started solving this yourself and are stuck at a certain point this is hard to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem here is **not** how to transform attributes to elements, but rather how to rename the already existing  `field` elements to the names given by their `name` attribute.

**Caveat**: I know practically nothing about MS Access, so I could be easily wrong about this. Try the following transformation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/form">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="record"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of applying this to your input example will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
   <row>
      <Date>2015-10-14</Date>
      <Hospital>OLVG</Hospital>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <VisitType>Handover</VisitType>
      <Specialisation>SYS1</Specialisation>
      <ContactName>Nick</ContactName>
      <ContactTel>0365425653</ContactTel>
      <ContactMail>Nick@new.nl</ContactMail>
      <ShortText>Dit is een test</ShortText>
      <Actions>Geen verdere acties nodig</Actions>
   </row>
</table>
```